# TCP HaProxy Error 400

Tags: haproxy

I set up a syslog generator to send logs using 514 and received via rsyslog (10.1.1.1) then using same host but diff port to set up HaProxy (10.1.1.1:1936) and from HaProxy to forward those logs to 2 diff server (10.1.1.4 & 10.1.1.5) using port 8088.

I did a TCPdump and saw that they have acknowledge handshake. But there is an error 400. Below is HAProxy config. Please advice which part I had missed out.

Thank you

```
global
log         127.0.0.1 local2
chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn     4000

# turn on stats unix socket
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats


stats timeout 30s
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon
# Default SSL material locations
ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
crt-base /etc/ssl/private
# Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
# For more information, see ciphers(1SSL).
ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:RC4- 
SHA:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL


defaults
mode                    http
log                     global
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
option accept-invalid-http-request
retries                 3
timeout http-request    10s
timeout queue           1m
timeout connect         10s
timeout client          1m
timeout server          1m
timeout http-keep-alive 10s
timeout check           10s
maxconn                 3000

listen main
bind 127.0.0.1:1936
mode tcp 

backend static
balance     roundrobin
server  No1 10.1.1.4:8088 ssl verify none check
server  No2 10.1.1.5:8088 ssl verify none check
```

Comment: try adding the directive `option accept-invalid-http-request` It relaxes some of the strict protocol compliance that HAProxy requires by default on incoming requests   
EDIT: didnt notice that you have already added that

Comment: Yea.. not sure why it keep prompting issue. If using tcp, don't need to set up web server right.